# Excel VBA on combining multiple formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am wondering how I should code VBA for excel to do automatically add up and delete based on multiple conditions automatically.

I included a picture of an example database.

[simple database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAlET.png)

How would the macro be written if I need excel to add up every row that has the same location/unit/tax and put the sum of those rows in the total cell? It needs to only keep the unique number of the first row that matches and delete all other rows. (eg A002 was added to A001 and so A002 was deleted)

Comment: Hi Scott, I see that the other one works similarly but not exactly. How do I tell excel to differentiate between ones with different taxes? The hard part is telling excel to add up only apples that are at 100% and also add up apples that are at 85%!

Thanks alot!

Comment: You would expand the SUMIFS() formula and the Remove Duplicates function to include those columns.  Try modifying it then if it is not working come back ask a new question with specific questions as to what is not working.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  You need to try on your own then come here with specific problems.

Comment: Will do. Thanks Scott.